# Adding a scrollBar to my text area and my image isnt showing

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm trying to add a scroll bar to my GUI but dont know how any ideas will do thanks. Also am not getting my image to display at all in my gui.

**Tried:**

Putting my image  in the same folder but it still isnt working.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package chatbot;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @auth
   private JLabel pic = new JLabel();
  private ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("chatt.jpg");

    //main class
    chatbot_display c=new chatbot_display();
    //JTextArea
    private JTextArea dis=new JTextArea();

    //JButton
    private final JButton send=new JButton();
    private final JButton clear=new JButton();
    private final JButton exit=new JButton();

    //JTextField
     final JTextField message=new JTextField();

    //Making the display bar scroll.


    public chatbot_gui(){


        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        super.setSize(400,400);
        super.setTitle("Nigel");
        super.setLayout(null);



        pic.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 300);
        pic.setIcon(icon);
        super.getContentPane().add(pic);

        //JTextArea Settings
        dis.setBounds(50,50, 300, 150);
        super.getContentPane().add(dis);
        dis.setEditable(false);//to prevent users from entering in the text area
        super.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);


         //JButton Setting
        this.send.setText("SEND");
        this.clear.setText("CLEAR");
        this.exit.setText("EXIT");
        send.setBounds(80,325, 75, 25);
        clear.setBounds(160,325, 75, 25);
        exit.setBounds(240,325, 75, 25);
        super.getContentPane().add(send).setBackground(Color.yellow);
        super.getContentPane().add(clear).setBackground(Color.yellow);
        super.getContentPane().add(exit).setBackground(Color.yellow);

        //JTextField Setting
        message.setBounds(50,250, 300, 50);
        super.getContentPane().add(message);

        //ActionListener
        clear.addActionListener(this);
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        send.addActionListener(this);
        super.setVisible(true);





    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String str = e.getActionCommand();//stores the string on the button and passes on to str.

        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit"))//if str equals Exit the JFrame.
            System.exit(0); 

         else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("CLEAR")){//begin
            //goes to the calculation class to do the method 
            c.clear(message);
        }//end

         else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("SEND")){

              String quote=message.getText();
              message.setText("");

          HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    // the ArrayList replaces your HashSet.
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();   // I called it list so you we can see the difference :)
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();   // I called it list so you we can see the difference :)

    Random r = new Random();

    list.add("Hello");
    list.add("Hi");
    list.add("How's you whats up");
    list.add("Hey");

    list1.add("Am gud");
    list1.add("looking to head to bed");
    list1.add("now from gym");
    list1.add("heading home");

    map.put("hi", list);
    map.put("hey", list);
    map.put("hello", list);

    map.put("whats up", list1);
    map.put("hows you", list1);
    map.put("hows things", list1);






    if (map.containsKey(quote)) {
        ArrayList<String> tmpList = map.get(quote);  // this is just make the step clear, that we now retrieve an ArrayList from the map
        int randomNumber = r.nextInt(tmpList.size()); // a random number between 0 and tmpList.size() 

        addText("---->You:\t"+quote+"\n");
        addText("---->Nigel:\t"+tmpList.get(randomNumber)+"\n");



    }





    System.out.println(map.containsKey(message));













    }// end of metthod 


    }
    private void addText(String str) {
        dis.setText(dis.getText()+str);

    }





}//end of class







        }
```

Comment: You want to use a [`JScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) <- click. And **don't** use a null layout. I can already see problems arising for your with the scroll pane. Use layout managers.

Comment: For your second question, I don't see any code where you're trying to add an image.

Answer (score 2):

> "Putting my image in the same folder but it still isnt working. "

Instead of trying to load the image by a file through the file system, by doing this

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("chatt.jpg");  
// String passed will be read as file path
```

Load it though a URL from the class path by doing this

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("chatt.jpg"));
// will be read from class path
```

And your file should be in the same package as the class calling it

```
ProjectRoot
          src
              chatbot
                    chatbot_gui.java
                    chatt.jpg
```

---

Also as noted in the comment above, you need to add a your `JTextArea` to a `JScrollPane` and add the `JScrollPane` to a container.

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
frame.add(scroll);
```

---

**Side Note**

- Use Java naming convention. Class names begin with capital letters.
- Avoid using null layout. Learn to use layout managers. You can learn more at [Laying out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- You don't need to call `super` on all the inherited method in your `JFrame` subclass.